# dyld monitors DYLD_ variables behind the scenes

Tags: bash, environment-variables, dynamic-library

If I invoke

```
DYLD_X=foo /bin/bash -c 'echo "<$DYLD_X>"'
```

the output is

```
<>
```

while

```
MY_VAR=bar /bin/bash -c 'echo "<$MY_VAR>"'
```

outputs

```
<bar>
```

Switching to Bash 5:

```
DYLD_X=foo /usr/local/bin/bash -c 'echo "<$DYLD_X>"'
```

the output is

```
dyld: warning, unknown environment variable: DYLD_X
<foo>
```

I would think that `dyld` should only monitor variables that it knows about. Is there anything that can be done to control this behavior?

MacOS Mojave 10.14.4

Comment: Macos does not like dyld variables the latest versions use sip and remove them. What are you trying to do

Comment: @Mark: I'm just trying to understand why this seemingly odd behavior occurs.

Comment: Basically Apple thinks it is insecure a way of injected unfriendly code into normal apps